# Which fields should be protected from mass assignment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security

I'm doing a security audit on a Rails 2.3.8 application and one of the things that has come up is our lack of `attr_protected` or `attr_accessible` in my model definitions. I understand the reasoning behind them, and have even [written a gem](https://github.com/beerlington/sudo_attributes) to assist with mass assignment, but I'm looking for attributes that I might potentially be missing.

The problem I have is determining which fields should be protected. Are there any rules that people generally follow for this? I'm thinking attributes like foreign keys and booleans like admin? would make sense to protect. I'm also wondering about fields like STI type, and  polymorphic *_type/*_id fields. I see that Rails 3 introduced [attributes protected by default](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-c-attributes_protected_by_default), but it doesn't appear that Rails 2.3.8 has this.

Any guidance on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: have a look at http://railscasts.com/episodes/237-dynamic-attr-accessible

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My general rule of thumb is that any attribute you don't want users to modify should be protected.

So in my models, I use `attr_accessible` for all attributes that are present as fields in forms. All others are protected. (I'd rather have everything protected by default.)

In other words: assume all data sent by clients will be maliciously tampered.

Edit: relevant blog post http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/09/22/security-lessons-learned-from-the-diaspora-launch/

Comment: I've always felt attr_protected to be a security risk (though its better than not using anything!)  Fields should be protected by default, which is what you get when using attr_accessible.

Comment: Yes, I fell the same way. I'd rather be secure by default and use tests to ensure attributes are writable when necessary.

Comment: I love when the answer that makes the most sense is the one I hadn't even thought of. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess every "potentially dangerous" attribute should be protected, like an admin flag for a user.

In my opinion, ideally, every model should have attr_accessible for all attributes that can be updated. It's the safer solution.