# "Couldn't find <object> without an ID"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, comments

I'm having problems implementing a kind of comments form, where comments (called "microposts") belong_to both users and posts, users have_many comments, and posts (called "propositions") have_many comments.

My code for the comments form is:

```
<%= form_for @micropost do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
      <%= f.text_area :content %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The MicropostsController has this in the create action:

```
  def create

      @proposition = Proposition.find(params[:proposition_id])

  @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(params[:micropost])
  @micropost.proposition = @proposition
  if @micropost.save
      flash[:success] = "Contribution submitted"
      redirect_to root_path
  else
          @feed_items = []    
      render 'pages/home'
  end
  end
```

The form for creating a new micropost is on the same page as a proposition, yet the proposition id doesn't seem to get passed at any point.

This is the error I get on submitting the micropost form:

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in
>   MicropostsController#create
>
> Couldn't find Proposition without an
>   ID

Parameters are:

> {"commit"=>"Submit", 
>   "micropost"=>{"proposition_id"=>"", 
>   "content"=>"First comment"}, 
>   "authenticity_token"=>"TD6kZaHv3CPWM7xLzibEbaLJHI0Uw43H+pq88HLZFjc=",
>   "utf8"=>"âœ“"}

I'm completely new to rails and very new to coding anything at all, so I'd be grateful for any help you can give me!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your params are:

```
"micropost"=>{"proposition_id"=>"", "content"=>"First comment"}
```

So to get `proposition_id`, you have to do :

```
params[:micropost][:proposition_id]
```

But this is empty. And there is nowhere else to get this `id`, that's why this line retrieves `nil`:

```
@proposition = Proposition.find(params[:proposition_id])
```

Making this fail:

```
@micropost.proposition = @proposition
```

You must either:

- add the `proposition_id` as an `hidden_field`
- store it in session

But I don't know your context enough to give you the proper solution here.

EDIT:

[In your link](https://github.com/jnwb2/the_app/blob/master/app/views/shared/_micropost_form.html.erb), replace:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :proposition_id %>
```

with:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :proposition_id, :value => @proposition.id %>
```

If it doesn't work, show your params.

Note: it's bad practice to rely on instance variables, you should send local variable to each partial

Comment: Thanks - I've added a hidden field but still not working. It's up on github here: [link](https://jnwb2@github.com/jnwb2/the_app.git). -- If you can tell me why Vim keeps creating all these swap files and how to stop it, please tell me!

Comment: Thanks for the edit. When I make this change (using <%= f.hidden_field :proposition_id, @proposition.id %>') I get the error message "undefined method `merge' for 34:Fixnum" - 34 being the ID of the proposition I want the form to pass to the controller. Is there some problem with the syntax of this code?

Answer (score 1):

As you can see, the `proposition_id` parameter is empty, so your controller can't find the proposition unless you give it a valid id.

You need to make sure your `new` form sends the `proposition_id` attribute. One way to do this is:

1. Set the proposition in the `new` action in the controller: `@micropost.proposition = ...`
2. In the form, add a hidden field for the id: `f.hidden_field :proposition_id`
3. In the `create` action, find the appropriate Proposition with `params[:micropost][:proposition_id]`

(You'll also want to make sure to use `attr_accessible` in your Micropost model, and make sure `proposition_id` is NOT in that list. Otherwise, you'll be open to nasty security holes. See http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/09/22/security-lessons-learned-from-the-diaspora-launch/ and [Which fields should be protected from mass assignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651579/which-fields-should-be-protected-from-mass-assignment))

EDIT (due to comment):

Your new action should be like this:

```
def new
  @micropost = Micropost.new
  @micropost.proposition_id = params[:proposition_id]
```

This is slightly different from what is said above, and is due to the fact you're sending the proposition id in the request to `new`. There's no need to look up the actual proposition record, since we're only interested in the `id` field (which we already have).

Comment: Thanks David! I've now added 1. '@proposition = Proposition.find(params[:proposition_id])' to the 'new' action in the controller; 2. '<%= f.hidden_field :proposition_id %>' to the form, and 3. '@proposition = Proposition.find(params[:micropost][:proposition_id])' to the 'create' action in the controller. I hope this is what you meant. I also have 'attr_accessible :content' in the Microposts controller. -- But I'm still getting the same error! Any idea why? It's all up on github here [link](https://jnwb2@github.com/jnwb2/the_app.git)

Comment: I've added this code but it's still resulting in the same error - I have no idea why... Sorry for my level of ignorance.

Comment: Thanks for your help David. I've managed to get this working with apneadiving's solution, but I suspect there is a way of doing this without using hidden form fields...